# How can I solve the stack corrupted error?

Tags: c, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation, stack-corruption

```
void aloca(automob **autos, int n)
{

    *autos = (automob*)malloc(sizeof(automob));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        autos[i] = (automob*)malloc(sizeof(automob));
    }
}

void read_autos(char* filename, automob **A, int *n)
{ 
    FILE *f_in = fopen(filename, "r");
    int i = 0, aux;
    if (f_in == NULL) {
        printf("Nu s-a gasit fisierul!");
        _getch();
        exit(0);
    }
    fscanf(f_in, "%d", n);
    aloca(A, *n);
    while (i < (*n)) {
        fscanf(f_in, "%d", &(*A)[i].locuri);
        fscanf(f_in, "%d", &(*A)[i].putere);
        fscanf(f_in, "%s", (*A)[i].marca);
        fscanf(f_in, "%s", (*A)[i].culoare);
        fscanf(f_in, "%d", &(*A)[i].an_fabricatie);
        i++;
    }
}

void main()
{
    int n;
    automob *A;
    read_autos("autos.in", &A, &n);
    _getch();
}
```

I get stack corrupted around A. How can I solve this problem? I think it is about the allocation but I don't know how to fix it. I really can't see the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`automob *A;` declaration means that you have a pointer to `automob` declared on stack, and `&A` is the pointer to that location on stack, and this is what you finally pass to `aloca` function.

`*autos = (automob*)malloc(sizeof(automob));`

allocates one `automob` and assigns that pointer to `A`, and this is fine.

Now,

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    autos[i] = (automob*)malloc(sizeof(automob));
}
```

is the issue. `autos[i]` is equivalent to `*(autos + i)`. `autos` is a pointer to the stack (it's what you passed to the function), and the size of that location on stack is `sizeof(automob *)`. With this code you try to store all the allocations you make on the stack near `&A` (declared in `main`), and eventually you will overwrite the stack guard (that is used by the runtime to keep stack integrity). To allocate n `automob`s you only need this:

`*autos = (automob*)malloc(sizeof(automob) * n);`

and you have the array of `automob`s and you can access it like this:

in `aloca`: `*autos[i]` is the i'th `automob`,

in `read_autos`: `*A[i]` is the i'th element,

and in `main`: `A[i]` is the i'th element.

Answer (score 0):

```
void aloca(automob **autos, int n)
{

    *autos = malloc(n * sizeof(automob));
}
```

and so on

you need to check for the error conditions like failed malloc or scanf

Comment: I agree that the `malloc()` is wrong.  However, I'm not convinced that the calls to `fscanf()` using `&(*A)[i].locuri` etc are wrong.  `*A` is the allocated array.  It's the middle of the night so I'm not about to compile the code, but please double check that.  (I have reservations about passing `A` to `aloca()`; but I definitely need to think it through before pontificating — I oscillate between OK and not OK.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler no you are right. The code is so badly formatted and I did not notice hat is still part of the function.